# Why is the Fullscreen API w3schools example not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

Does anyone know why the fullscreen api does not work on Firefox? The w3schools example does not work either. I don't get any response from the button clicks.
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_fullscreen2

I am trying to do a fullscreen div via a button click. It works in Chrome but not Firefox

Comment: First web developer rule: ALWAYS look the Developer Tools console.

Answer (score 3):

Open the developer tools. Look at the console. Firefox will tell you why.

> Request for fullscreen was denied because at least one of the document's containing elements is not an iframe or does not have an "allowfullscreen" attribute.

Comment: I think @skydev wanted a solution